# Django Template - show many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm learning Django after having built some basic apps in Flask. One thing I want to do is show users a list of all posts and whether or not they follow that given post. However, Jinja or Django is throwing some error that I don't quite know how to debug.

`Models.py`

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=120,blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=False)

class Record(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Follow')

class Follow(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    record = models.ForeignKey(Record)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_followed = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

`records.html`

```
{% for i in records %}

  {% if i.follow.filter(id='1').first() %}
    DO SOMETHING
  {% endif %}     

{% endfor %}
```

error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /records/
Could not parse the remainder: '(id='1').first()' from 'i.follow.filter(id='1').first()'
```

To test this out when I run the `python manage.py shell` and execute the following I have no issues:

```
>>> x = Record.objects.first()
>>> x.followers.filter(id='1').first()
  <User: User object>
```

I had initially prototyped this app using Flask and had the following jinja template and never had an issue:

```
{% for i in accounts %}

  {% if i.follow.filter_by(user_id='1').first() %}
    DO SOMETHING
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why not `i.followers.filter(id='1').first()` as you do in the shell on `x`?

Comment: error here: `Could not parse the remainder: '(id='1').first()' from 'i.follow.filter(id='1').first()'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that logic in template. You can create a method in Record model that does it for you and you can call it in template

```
class Record(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Follow')

    def first_follower(self):
        if self.follow_set.filter(user_id=1).exists():
            return True
        return False
```

and in template:

```
{% for i in records %}
    {% if i.first_follower %}
         DO SOMETHING
    {% endif %}     
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Got it. Here's the rub. `user_id=1` will end up being dynamic. Any thoughts on how to make that work in this situation?

Comment: I updated the code to allow the parameter of the user_id: `def is_followed(self,user_id):` and the template `{% if i.is_followed('1') %}` but am getting the error: `Could not parse the remainder: '('1')' from 'i.is_followed('1')'`

Comment: This is quite clever, clean, and scalable!

Answer (score 1):

This is by design https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1199

The idea is that a django template should focus on design, for designers, and let the more complex code run in Python, not when the template renders.

So if this is a single instance when you use this check, add it to the view:

```
def get_context_data(self,*arg,**kwargs):

  context = super(MyRecordView,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
  context[has_follow] = self.object.follow.filter_by(user_id='1').exists()
  return context
```

In the template:

```
{% if has_follow %}
...
{% endif %}
```

However, if you use this check a lot, you can add it to your model:

```
def has_follow(self):
   return self.follow.filter_by(user_id='1').exists()
```

And then you can access it in a template, w/o any changes to the view context, since it's a model attribute:

```
{% if i.has_follow %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. This helps a lot. How would you go about making `user_id='1'` dynamic? In reality it'd generally be something like `user_id=current_user.id` but there's no real way to add that to the models/views is there?

Comment: If you filter by the same user, you don't need the filter at all: `user.follow_set` gives you an objects manager for all the user related follows by the foreign key. `user.follow_set.all()` are all the follows